# how do I assign pins on GPIO expander mcp23017 to a 2nd i2c bus

Tags: gpio

So I've got a device on my pi that takes up almost all of the GPIO pins on the pi, but the device nicely has an MCP23017 on board, giving me an extra  GPIO pin, number 496 - 503

What I want to do is make another i2c bus, with 497 being SDA and 498 being SCL

I've searched and searched, and I'm stuck.

Tried using:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=497,i2c_gpi_scl=498
```

in `/boot/config.txt` but that doesn't seem to work (no additional i2c bus is created in /dev)...

I honestly don't have a clue if I'm even on the right track here.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Can you please give us a little bit more information? The pin numbers you're referring to neither match the pin numbering of a Pi nor that of a MCP23017 - at least not the chip itself but maybe that of a certain board. However since those pin numbers certainly do not refer to the Pi there is no use in specifying them in the dtoverlay.

Comment: Why do you want a 2nd i2c bus? I2c devices can be daisy chained on the same 2 pins!